# Dojo and/or javascript: onclick event for the scrollbar in a multiselect

Tags: javascript, select, dojo, onclick, disabled-input

I have a multiselect on a page, and I have set it up so that when one of the options is clicked another select on the page is disabled. The issue I am having is the client wants to have the other select disabled even if the user just clicks on the scrollbar of the multiselect. I have the onclick event on the select tag. Is there away to trigger the script if the user clicks on the scrollbar of the multiselect?

```
<select name="disable_this" id="disable_this" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" data-dojo-props="maxHeight:300" style="width:500px; overflow:hidden;" onclick="javascript:disableOtherSelect('thisone_multiple','disable_this');">
                    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                    <option>first</option>
                    <option>second</option>
                    <option>third</option>
                </select>



<select name="thisone_multiple" id="thisone_multiple" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.MultiSelect" multiple="multiple" data-dojo-props="maxHeight:300" style="width:500px; overflow:hidden;" onclick="javascript:disableOtherSelect('disable_this','thisone_multiple');">
                <option selected="selected">Select</option>
                    <option>C - Example Account Name 1</option>
                    <option>A - Example Account Name 2</option>
                    <option>B - Example Account Name 3</option>
                    <option>ZZ - Example Account Name 4</option>
                    <option>AA - Example Account Name 5</option>
                </select>


function disableOtherSelect(layer,layer2){
        //disable the other one based on arguments from the onchange event
      dijit.byId(layer2).set('disabled', false);
      dijit.byId(layer).set('disabled', true);


    };
```

***UPDATE***

I have created a simple jsfiddle that shows an onclick on a select versus a multiselect. As you will see, clicking the scrollbar on the multiselect does not trigger the script, but clicking the arrow on the select does trigger script:

http://jsfiddle.net/txujL/2/

Comment: I'd argue there are UX issues that need to be resolved here first. What is the argument for disabling a form element via interacting (but not selecting) another?

Comment: Probably because the client sees the reverse. For the one that is no a multiselect (its a regular dojo dropdown select), as soon as you click the dropdown arrow the multiselect is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better way to do this. Rather than disabling the form inputs, I set them up so that when one is clicked on a semi-transparent div appears over the other, effectively preventing the user from making a selection in the "disabled" one.